# Javascript - Como posso passar um objeto json no constructor da minha classe?

Tags: javascript, json, classes, objetos

Boa tarde, estou com uma dúvida referente a parâmetros onde passa um objeto, por exemplo no `mongoose` tem um método `connect` a qual passamos a `url` de conexão + um `objeto` para definir as opções, e é nisso que estou com um pouco de dúvida, como criar isso:

Como posso fazer o mesmo, em uma classe? passando no `construtor` essas opções a qual o usuário irá alimentar esse objeto com definições feitas por mim por exemplo.

```
class Teste {
    constructor(arg1, options = {}) {

    }
}
```

Pelo que testei se eu fazer dessa forma `options = {}` eu consigo passar um objeto para o constructor, mas o problema é que eu consigo passar qualquer coisa, se eu quiser passar 1mil chaves e valores eu consigo, eu queria que fosse igual ao exemplo que dei do `mongoose` ao entrar no parâmetro de `options`, se eu apertar no VScode Control + Espaço irei poder ver todas as opções que posso definir, não sei se conseguir seu claro no que eu quero, de forma resumida como posso fazer para receber no constructor um objeto com propriedades definidas por mim?

Comment: Você quer receber um objeto no construtor, mas precisa ser um objeto definido, com as propriedades que você espera, tipado?

Comment: @DanielMendes bom sou iniciante no Javascript, mas só de você ter falado tipado quer dizer que só tem como fazer com TypeScript? :/ eu queria exatamente isso que você está falando, mas se possível só com Javascript, eu sei que Typescript não é uma outra linguagem e sim um superset mas, queria ficar no momento só com Javascript.

Comment: É, pelo que conheço, em JS você não vai conseguir esse resultado, você pode partir para TS ou receber o objeto e efetuar as validações que deseja, procurando as propriedades etc.

Comment: Entendi, ouvi falar que com instanceof daria para fazer algo semelhante, irei procurar a respeito.

Comment: Magno, você gostaria de passar toda a instancia (métodos e parâmetros) de um objeto para dentro de outro objeto e utilizar eles lá?

Answer (score 1):

Magno, para passar parâmetros para o construtor de uma classe, tudo o que você precisa fazer é instancia-la e dentro do parenteses adicionar o parâmetro que quer resgatar dentro da classe, exemplo:

```
class Teste {
    constructor(objetoJson) {
      alert(objetoJson.valorA);
    }
}

const meuJson = {
 valorA: 'texto',
 valorB: 20,
 valorC: 'etc',
};

new Teste(meuJson);
```

Basta você receber os valores vindo deste json dentro de uma variavel e enviar para a classe.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, então isso ai eu sabia que para passar um json na instancia de uma classe, eu precisaria no contrutor informar algo lá, mas o que eu queria mesmo fazer era restringir as informações que são passadas dentro desse objeto json, para que o usuário não informe nada que não foi determinado por mim antes, por exemplo você passou no seu json o: valorA, valorB e valorC, vamos supor que eu só permita que você passe a chave valorA e as outras não serão permitidas, pelo que me responderem nessa pergunta só da pra fazer isso com Typescript.

Comment: Da pra você fazer um "whitelist" e depois mapear o objeto json com a função map ou filter do js, e aí determinar o que pode ou não ser passado para a classe. Isso você pode fazer antes, ou dentro do próprio construtor.